# WCF Serialization with abstract class

Tags: wcf, inheritance, serialization, abstract-class

I have a contract defined like this :

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
 public class CommandWebService : ICommandWebService
 {
     public ExecuteResponse Execute(CommandBase command)
     {
     ...
     }
 }
```

with Command base being an abstract class :

```
[Serializable]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public abstract class CommandBase : Message, ICommand
{
     public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
     {
         var types = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                     from type in asm.GetTypes()
                     where typeof(CommandBase).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsAbstract
                     select type;

         return types.ToArray();
     }
}
```

These I used in another project to instantiate my WCF service:

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"); ;
var commandHandler = new CommandHandlerService();
var projectionHandler = new ProjectionHandlerService();
var commandWebService = new CommandWebService(bus, commandHandler, projectionHandler);

using (var commandServiceHost = new ServiceHost(commandWebService))
{
     commandServiceHost.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("service started");
     var quitFlag = false;
     while (!quitFlag)
     {
         var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
         quitFlag = keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C
                    && keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control;
      }
}
```

with the following  serviceModel:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings/>
        <services>
            <service name="CommandService.CommandWebService" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1338/MyApp"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          contract="CommandService.ICommandWebService"/>
                <endpoint address="mex"
                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

*I have added and removed the following but it does not change the problem.*

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
  <dataContractSerializer>
     <declaredTypes>
       <add type="CommonDomain.CommandBase, CommonDomain, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral">
           <knownType type="MyNamespace.Cmd1, MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
           <knownType type="MyNamespace.Cmd2, MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
           <knownType type="MyNamespace.Cmd3, MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>

       </add>
    </declaredTypes>
  </dataContractSerializer>
</system.runtime.serialization>
```

Doing so works well. The service start, and then I can reference it in my console application, which gives me the following reference :

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]     
 [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="Contabilita.ICommandWebService")]
 public interface ICommandWebService 
 {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ICommandWebService/Execute", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ICommandWebService/ExecuteResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyNamespace.Cmd1))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyNamespace.Cmd2))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(MyNamespace.Cmd3))]
        MyConsole.Ref1.ExecuteResponse Execute(Common.CommandBase command);
    }
```

The call to my web service is detailed here :

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var cmdCreate = Build.Cmd1
                     .ForCreationDate(DateTime.Now)
                     .ForDescription("test")
                     .Build(id);

var client = new Ref1.CommandWebServiceClient();

client.Execute(cmdCreate);
```

The resulting message has the correct id because this information is part of CommandBase the abstract class , but creationdate and description are not part of the xml.

Is there something I omitted?

[EDIT]
One important thing I omitted to say. I do not want any attribute on my command class.
[/EDIT]

Thanks for your reading,

Comment: Ok found the solution.. sorry for disturbing your sleep.
My command Cmd1 had private setters for description and creation date... I am going to delete this question...

Comment: you should answer it yourself and mark the answer as solution to help other users with a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIke said in the comment, my command Cmd1 had private setters for description and creation date. Like using WCF, I am using xmlserializer, there are two things to know :

there must be a nude ctor 
the property must have a public setter in order to be serialized.

I'll have a lokk now at changing if I may from xml serializer to something different to bypass these two hinders.